# How to get my Spinner to show String value from my Integer Array list?

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

I had to create a spinner with each item a different color. 
I managed to accomplish this but now instead of the text value showing up with the color that is shown, it's just showing up as blank.

I've tried using the `txv.setText()` but this is not what I want.

I want it to use my array list values, here's what I have vs what it should look like:

[image]

Part of the code for my custom adapter using `BaseAdapter` in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
    TextView txv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    txv.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(pos));
    txv.setTextSize(20f);
    return view;
}
```

Here's my list in `strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Pallete Activity</string>

    <item name="white" type="color">#FFF</item>
    <item name="red" type="color">#FF00</item>
    <item name="yellow" type="color">#FF0</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#4ee900</item>
    <item name="blue" type="color">#0000FF</item>

    <array name="pallete">
        <item>@color/white</item>
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/yellow</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/blue</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Comment: You need to use a custom layout, instead of using the default android simple_spinner_dropdown_item, create your own and add a text view to it, then you can set the background as well as the text.

Comment: @JudeFernandes I just did it but I don't know how to make it so that the background is a different color for each of the items listed in the dropdown.

Comment: I suggest you google how to create a custom spinner adapter, there are more than enough examples online. http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html or http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/01/10/custom-spinner-android-redone-baseadapter/